# How to change page with UISlider from an UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uipageviewcontroller

To summarize my app, it's like an iBook : I have multiple pages filled in with an xml file (text and image).
Like in the iBook app, I want to use a UISlider to select and change page.

I use a UIViewController (appViewController) as contener of the different UIViews (contentViewController)

header of AppViewController :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "contentViewController.h"

@interface AppViewController : UIViewController <UIPageViewControllerDataSource>
{
    UIPageViewController *pageController;
    NSArray *pageContent;
    NSDictionary *pageFields;
}
```

in AppViewController.m, I have :

```
// Create a new view controller and pass suitable data.
    contentViewController *dataViewController = [[contentViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"contentViewController" bundle:nil];
```

The header of the contentViewController is :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class DCIEquipment;

@interface contentViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic,strong) DCIEquipment *eqt;

@property (assign, nonatomic) NSUInteger pageIndex;
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSUInteger pageNumber;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *pageSlider;

@end
```

Because in iBook, the slider seems to follow the curling movement of the page, I put my UISlider on the contentViewController. Everything works good with the UISlider but I don't how know to do to informe the UIViewController to change the page (I assumed that the code of changing the page has to be done in this controller).

Please tell me if you need some more code. I hope that explainations are clear. I juste want to know where to put the UISlider (which view) and how to send value to the pageViewController.

Thank you in advance.

Raphael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [protocols](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html). There are lots of examples. And you are using at least one of them (UIPageViewControllerDataSource).

Just create one for your contentViewController (in it's header file)

```
@class ContentViewController; // this is fast-forward declaration
@protocol ContentViewControllerDelegate

- (void)contentViewController:(ContentViewController *)controller didChangePage:(NSUInteger)pageIndex;

@end

@interface ContentViewController : UIViewController
// ...
@property (weak,nonatomic) id<ContentViewControllerDelegate> delegate; // don't forget to set the value with your appViewController
// ...
@end
```

In your ContentViewController-implementation file in some method just call the delegate method

```
if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(contentViewController:didChangePage:)])
    [self.delegate contentViewController:self didChangePage:newIndex];
```

And don't forget to implement this method in appViewController class.

Comment: I'm not sure to well understand : for the property `delegate`, you tell me that I don't have to forget to set the value with my appViewController. How do I do this ? I tryed with `self.delegate = [super parentViewController];` but I have an incompatible type error. Moreovet, I assume the method `didChangePage:` has to be implemented in my contentViewController-implement file too, no ?

Comment: @Oby1 yep, you should add in `appViewController` headers <ContentViewControllerDelegate> protocol and implement `didChangePage:` method inside it.

Comment: I need some times to understand that the delegate property has to be set in the appViewController.m ! Moreover, I change the `id` by `NSObject`for the delegate property to avoid the **'No known Instance method for selector 'respondsToSelector:'** error for `if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(contentViewController:didChangePage:)])`. It could help some one to know ;o) Thanks for the help and the quick answer :o)